# Totally wrong rear springs fitted to car during factory production

Tags: suspension, springs

One year on since buying a new car and we've finally acheived confirmation that the wrong rear springs were fitted to the car - in the factory production line. Apparently the springs were those for a totally different vehicle model. Apart from being a very uncomfortable ride since buying it in Aug '17 and incredulity that this could happen, how dangerous could this be?

Comment: Who knows - what are both models? How do the suspension travel distances differ? what are the differences in mass?  Need a LOT more detail, but whatever it is not good...

Comment: Ours is a FIAT Qubo.  No idea of other model involved and the problem springs "had to be returned to FIAT" so unsure whether that question will ever be (truthfully) answered.  Sorry, I have no mechanical knowledge (which questions why I am here!).